# Calculate number of days between dates using IF,INDEX,MATCH functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a complicated case here.

[image: Please refer to the image for the question]

I am working on an inventory stock list, basically I want the Column "Days of Storage" to show the number of days the inventory sit in the warehouse.

I have already come up with the formula for "Out" of inventory using IF, INDEX AND MATCH functions, but not for "In" inventory. I want the column for "Days of Storage" for "In" to have the same number of days of storage as the "Out" of inventory.

Do note that if the stock is sold, there will be a corresponding "Out" linked by the "index number". When the stock is not sold, there is no corresponding "Out" because the inventory is still in the warehouse, wondering what formula would work for this. Really appreciate your help and please clarify with me if the question is confusing.
Thanks!

Comment: @BigBen I have already edited the question to make it clearer. so for every addition into inventory on a certain date, an index number will be attached to this transaction. When this stock is sold to a buyer, that would be another transaction with a unique index number attached. So how we identify which stock was sold to which person, was through the column "Out from index number?", that is why we used MATCH function. the expected result would be to have a formula for the column "Days of storage" to calculate the number of days difference between "in" and "out".

Answer (score 1):

Have a try on below formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH(D2,$D$2:$D$5,0))-INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH(D2,$C$2:$C$5,0)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I think we are on the right track!! Hmmm is it possible to add one extra day to the result? like the difference between the two dates +1 day, so that DS result will include the day itself? If it is possible, where could we add the +1? Thanks!!

Comment: @Kangaroo At the last of formula like `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH(D2,$D$2:$D$5,0))-INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH(D2,$C$2:$C$5,0)),"")+1`.

Comment: If i add that +1 at the back, the formula will not work for the "in" status. Another difficulty i faced is that the formula will not work when the status is "in" but there is no corresponding "Out" because the stock has not been sold yet, this formula does not seem to work.

Comment: So, what is you expected out for `In` transactions? Suppose what will be result in `E2` cell as per above screenshot.

Comment: so if there is a corresponding "Out", E2 should show Sold? and if there is no corresponding "Out" then E2 can either be blank or it says "Unsold"? Hmm Maybe it is too demanding to put everything in one formula, it is also possible that we split the formula and add extra column of data? like the column on Sold or Unsold, and then calculate the number of days?

Comment: Little confusing to me. Can you please edit your question and put your exact expected output to screenshot.

Comment: okay let me tidy it up again, it is quite confusing right now.